# How do you assign unique factor to multiple values in R?

Tags: r

Say I have a data set of numbers from 0 to 20
And I want to create a 3 different age groups 
from 0~9 yrs old, 10~15 yrs old, and 16~20 yrs old

How do I assign 3 factors to a set of numbers from 0 to 20
corresponding to their particular value?

So for example, values between 0 and 9 will be assigned "0~9 yrs old" factor
and 10 to 15 will be assigned "10~15 yrs old" factor, and so forth

How do I do this in R?

Comment: What have you done so far and why have you added python tag?

Answer (score 0):

The `case_when` function would do the trick. Try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(age = 1:20)

df %>% 
  mutate(age_categories = case_when(age <= 9 ~ "0~9 years old",
                                    age <= 15 & age > 9 ~ "10~15 years old",
                                    age <= 20 & age > 15 ~ "16~20 years old",
                                    TRUE ~ "Other"))
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
     age  age_categories
   <int>           <chr>
 1     1   0~9 years old
 2     2   0~9 years old
 3     3   0~9 years old
 4     4   0~9 years old
 5     5   0~9 years old
 6     6   0~9 years old
 7     7   0~9 years old
 8     8   0~9 years old
 9     9   0~9 years old
10    10 10~15 years old
11    11 10~15 years old
12    12 10~15 years old
13    13 10~15 years old
14    14 10~15 years old
15    15 10~15 years old
16    16 16~20 years old
17    17 16~20 years old
18    18 16~20 years old
19    19 16~20 years old
20    20 16~20 years old
```

Alternatively, you could do the following:

```
df$age_categories <- factor(df$age)

levels(df$age_categories) <- list(
  "0~9 years old" = 1:9,
  "10~15 years old" = 10:15,
  "16~20 years old" = 16:20
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `base::cut` (R)/`pandas.cut` (Python)?

```
df <- data.frame(age = 0:20)
labels = sprintf("from %s yrs old", c("0~9","10~15","16~20")
df$groups <- cut(
  df$age, 
  breaks=c(0,9,15,20), 
  include.lowest = T, 
  labels = labels)
)
df$groups
# [1] from 0~9 yrs old   from 0~9 yrs old   from 0~9 yrs old   from 0~9 yrs old   from 0~9 yrs old   from 0~9 yrs old  
# [7] from 0~9 yrs old   from 0~9 yrs old   from 0~9 yrs old   from 0~9 yrs old   from 10~15 yrs old from 10~15 yrs old
# [13] from 10~15 yrs old from 10~15 yrs old from 10~15 yrs old from 10~15 yrs old from 16~20 yrs old from 16~20 yrs old
# [19] from 16~20 yrs old from 16~20 yrs old from 16~20 yrs old
# Levels: from 0~9 yrs old from 10~15 yrs old from 16~20 yrs old
```

and

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':range(20)})
labels = ['from %s yrs old' % x for x in ['0~9','10~15','16~20']]
df.groups = pd.cut(
  df.age,
  bins = [0,9,15,20],
  include_lowest=True, labels = labels)
df.groups
#0       from 0~9 yrs old
#1       from 0~9 yrs old
#2       from 0~9 yrs old
#3       from 0~9 yrs old
#4       from 0~9 yrs old
#5       from 0~9 yrs old
#6       from 0~9 yrs old
#7       from 0~9 yrs old
#8       from 0~9 yrs old
#9       from 0~9 yrs old
#10    from 10~15 yrs old
#11    from 10~15 yrs old
#12    from 10~15 yrs old
#13    from 10~15 yrs old
#14    from 10~15 yrs old
#15    from 10~15 yrs old
#16    from 16~20 yrs old
#17    from 16~20 yrs old
#18    from 16~20 yrs old
#19    from 16~20 yrs old
#Name: age, dtype: category
#Categories (3, object): [from 0~9 yrs old < from 10~15 yrs old < from 16~20 yrs old]
```